# update product price list with the same name list from import path excel file

Tags: python, excel, string, odoo

```
class data_migration(osv.osv):
      _name = 'excel.product.tmp'
      _description = 'Data Migration For Excel' 
      _columns = {
            'db_name':fields.char('DB Name'),
            'excel_file': fields.char('Excel File Path',size = 200),
            'sheet_name':fields.char('Excel Sheet Name'),
            }
def import_data(self,cr,uid,ids,context=None):

        for data2 in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
        file_path = data2.excel_file
        sheet_name_1 = data2.sheet_name
        db_name_1 = data2.db_name
       # connection for DB
        conn_string = "dbname='"+ db_name_1+"' user='openerp' password='openpgpwd' host='localhost'"
        conn = psycopg2.connect(conn_string)
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        # read the excel file
        wb_c = openpyxl.reader.excel.load_workbook(file_path)
        s_c  = wb_c.get_sheet_by_name(name=sheet_name_1)
        d_c = s_c.calculate_dimension()
        r_c = s_c.range(d_c)
        for row in r_c:
            product_id_from_excel =row[0].value
            statement = "select id from product_template where LOWER(name)=LOWER('"+product_id_from_excel+"')"
            cursor.execute(statement)
            conn.commit()
            product_id = cursor.fetchone()
            if product_id == None:
                list_price_from_excel = row[1].value
                statement = "UPDATE product_template SET list_price='"+list_price_from_excel+"' WHERE id = '"+product_id+"'"
                cursor.execute(statement)
                conn.commit()  

data_migration()
```

error show from console when update from path excel file
        statement = "UPDATE product_template SET list_price='"+list_price_from_excel+"'WHERE id = '"+product_id+"'"

```
  TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, NoneType found
```

Answer (score 0):

You loop condition is:

```
if product_id == None:
```

Then you are trying to insert `product_id` (which has the value of `None`) in your query. Since `None` is not a string but rather a `NoneType` - something that cannot be converted to a string, you are getting this error.

You should also read the [db api faq](https://wiki.python.org/moin/DbApiFaq) to understand how to properly use the db api.